# Card battle in prolog

Tags: prolog

I have to write [card battle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_(card_game)) in prolog. I have problem with `battle` function in this function players should show theirs cads and fist winner is getting all that were shown.

Problem is that my function `battle` for any kind of input return `false`. 
Next thing is that I don't know how to return two values from this function... even if it will work correctly.

This is my complete code, mabye sb can assist me with this, I am not professional in prolog.

```
war([],[]):-write(' no results, all winners!!!'),!,fail.
war(_,[]):-write(' First player won! '),!,fail.
war([],_):-write(' Second player won! '),!,fail.
war([X1|X],[Y1|Y]):-write(' Player1 cards: '),displayKards([X1|X]),
    write(' PLayer2 cards: '),displayKards([Y1|Y]),check(X1,Y1),
    (  X1 =:=Y1
    -> write(' elements equal its time to start battle-> '),
       battle([X1|X],[Y1|Y],RES,OWNER)
    ;  X1 >Y1
    -> append(X,[Y1],X2),war(X2,Y)
    ;  append(Y,[X1],Y2),war(X,Y2) 
    ),
    war(X,Y).

check(X,Y):-write(' Checking '),write(X),write(':'),write(Y),true.

displayKards([]):-write('!').
displayKards([X|T]):-write(X),write(' '),displayKards(T).

battle([X1|X],[Y1|Y],WYN,OWNER) :-
    (  X1=:=Y1
    -> append([X1|Y1],WYN,WYN1),OWNER is 0,
       battle(X,Y,WYN1,OWNER)
    ;  X1>Y1
    -> append([X1|Y1],WYN,WYN1),append(X,WYN1,X2),OWNER is 1,
       battle(X,Y,X2,OWNER)
    ;  append([X1|Y1],WYN,WYN1),append(Y,WYN1,Y2),OWNER is -1,
       battle(X,Y,Y2,OWNER)                       
    ).
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Quick comment: `(=@=)/2` meaning structural equivalence modulo variable renaming should most probably read `(=:=)/2` meaning arithmetical equivalence

Comment: of course I will edit my post:)

Comment: And how is it called?

Comment: @Daniel it might be called `war([5,4],[5,4,6,7]).` -> player2 should win.
`war([5,4,2,8],[5,4,1,7]).` - player1 should win

Comment: You have three problems I see: the one causing the failure is `append([X1|Y1],...` in battle. You can't make a list by stapling together two items like that. Additionally, you have two singleton variables: `RES` and `OWNER` which you must fix or it will certainly not do what you want.

Comment: @false I know that so I am writing question on stack. I don't know how to resolve it.

Comment: @Rafik991: (Sorry, I doubt you know that it will never succeed). If you want help you need to make clearer statements about `battle/4`.  Give examples when it should succeed etc. It's impossible to guess.

Comment: Battle is according to link that I gave its battle in War card game, when there is sittuation that players have the same cards with the same value and then battle starts. In battle players need to give card by card and player that fist will have greater win battle and take all cards that appear in this battle.

Comment: 'If the face-up cards are again equal then the battle repeats with another set of face-down/up cards. This repeats until one player's face-up card is higher than their opponent's.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my problem. This is my solution. It is implementation of `card war game`. According to this wiki url: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_(card_game)

```
       :- use_module(library(lists)).

war([],[]):-write(' no results, all winners!!!'),!,fail.
war(X,[]):-write(' First player won! '),displayKards(X),!,fail.
war([],Y):-write(' Second player won! '),displayKards(Y),!,fail.
war([X1|X],[Y1|Y]):-write(' Player1 cards: '),displayKards([X1|X]),
    write(' PLayer2 cards: '),displayKards([Y1|Y]),check(X1,Y1),
    ( X1 =:=Y1 -> write(' elements equal its time to start battle-> '),battle([X1|X],[Y1|Y],_); 
        X1 >Y1 -> append(X,[Y1],X2),war(X2,Y) ; append(Y,[X1],Y2),war(X,Y2) 
    )
    ,war(X,Y).

check(X,Y):-write(' Checking '),write(X),write(':'),write(Y),true.

displayKards([]):-write('!').
displayKards([X|T]):-write(X),write(' '),displayKards(T).

battle([X1|_],[Y1|_],L):-X1>Y1,write(' player1 won battle'),append([X1],[Y1],L).
battle([X1|_],[Y1|_],L):-X1<Y1,write(' player2 won battle'),append([X1],[Y1],L).
battle([X1|X],[X1|Y],L):- write('elements'),write(X1),write(':'),write(X1),
    write(' are equal battle will be continued '),
    battle(X,Y,L1),append(L1,[X1],L2),append(L2,[X1],L3),decide(X,Y,L3,L).

decide(X,Y,[X1,Y1|L4],L):- X1>Y1,append(X,[X1,Y1|L4],L),displayKards(L),war(L,Y).
decide(X,Y,[X1,Y1|L4],L):- X1<Y1,append(Y,[X1,Y1|L4],L),displayKards(L),war(X,L).
```

This is simple example of usage this game and result.

```
war([1,2,3,4,2],[1,2,3,4,8]).
Player1 cards: 1 2 3 4 2 ! PLayer2 cards: 1 2 3 4 8 ! 
Checking 1:1 elements equal its time to start battle-> 
elements1:1 are equal battle will be continued elements2:2 
are equal battle will be continued elements3:3 are equal battle will be continued elements4:4 
are equal battle will be continued player2 won battle2 8 4 4 !
Player1 cards: 2 ! PLayer2 cards: 8 2 8 4 4 ! Checking 2:8 Second player won! 2 8 4 4 2 !false
```

The only interesting thing is that why Player2 is not getting all cards from battle...-> why battle is not collecting all cards from it?

for me result for

`battle([1,2,3,4,2],[1,2,3,4,8],L)`
 should be like that
 `[2, 8, 4, 4 ,3 ,3 ,2 ,2 ,1 ,1]`

Maybe sb can elaborate on that?